# When is it required that a non-resident alien file tax returns in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, dtaa

I am a non-resident alien as per US IRS definition. I generate some income from the US on account of book royalties and advance from a U.S. publisher. I am otherwise employed full-time in India and file my tax returns in India. Do I need to additionally file returns in the U.S? If so, is there a minimum income slab below which returns don't need to be filed in this case?

Comment: Have you checked the Indo-US tax treaty wrt the royalties?

Comment: Yes, but my question is about filing returns, not quantum of taxation per se

Comment: If you need to claim treaty benefits - you need to file returns.

Comment: @littleadv not so. To claim treaty benefits, one needs to have an ITIN and use it to fill out form W8-BEN, that's all.

Comment: incorrect. You're thinking about the withholding rates, which is not really a benefit since withholding is not an actual tax.

Comment: @littleadv thanks. could you please provide a link to treaty benefits other than withholding rates?

Comment: https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/International-Businesses/United-States-Income-Tax-Treaties---A-to-Z

Answer (score 1):

In the first few pages of the 1040NR instructions for each year, there is a section called "Who Must File". That will answer your question.